# Receive multiple objects by objectinputstream but only refresh them after sending objectoutputstream

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, server, client

So my problem is I have a client with a Runnable that readobjects in background from the socket. In the server i send multiple times objects like notifications updates etc by writeUnshared, but the client is only receiving them when I send a request back to server by writeUnshared.

\ClientThread.java\

```
public class ThreadClientInFromServer implements Runnable {
Socket socket;
ClientData clientData;

public ThreadClientInFromServer(Socket socket, ClientData clientData) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.clientData = clientData;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    ObjectInputStream in;
    ObjectOutputStream out;

    out = clientData.getOut();
    in = clientData.getIn();
    while (!socket.isClosed()) {
        try {

            Object object = in.readObject();

                clientData.updateData(object);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

SendRequestClient.java Only when i send this request it refresh and come the updates,notifications,etc

```
public void sendRequest(Request request) {

    try {
        out.writeObject(request);
        out.flush();
        out.reset();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("[ERROR] ON SEND REQUEST!");
        return;
    }
}
```

On Server (KEEPALIVETCP.java) for example, he doesnt receive.

```
public class KeepAliveTCP implements Runnable {
ServerModel serverModel;

public KeepAliveTCP(ServerModel serverModel) {
    this.serverModel = serverModel;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Request request = new Request(null, Constants.ACK);
    while (!serverModel.getSocket().isClosed()) {
        try {
            for (SocketModel clients : serverModel.getModelClientes()) {
                if (clients.getNome() != null) {
                    clients.getOut().writeUnshared(request);
                    clients.getOut().flush();
                }
            }
            sleep(5000);
            watchWhoFails();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

EDIT : So I was trying to find a solution and come up with my cliente blocking the thread(ThreadClientInFromServer) when he uses scanner.next() on the menus(that user uses to browse on the application). So I dont really know how to solve this problem, if you guys know some solution for this!

Thanks.